# Sitecore search (SOLR and AzureSearch), top 5 results grouped by category

Tags: azure, search, solr, sitecore

I'm trying to implement a slightly more complex query with Sitecore Content Search and I'm a bit stuck.

I want my query to return the top 5 search result items per category (which is stored as string value in the index - category_name_s ). For example, if the available categories are "news", "event" and "page" the search should return the top 5 events, 5 news and 5 pages matching the search terms.

This should be achievable with a GroupBy(category) and  SelectMany Take(5), but when I perform the search I'm getting a negative index exception.

I have been doing some reading and I'm not sure if LINQ to Sitecore supports groupBy. I also found an article on the sitecore website pointing to the "grouping" function available in the SOLR extension library, but I am actually using azure search in production and I'd prefer if my search is search provider agnostic.

Do you have any suggestion? Is there a different way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above results using Azure search query itself.

```
{ 
  queryType: 'full',
  search: 'Search category:"Search string" ',
  facets: [ 'resultCategory1,count:5','resultCategory2,count:5','resultCategory3,count:5'] 
}
```

I am assuming you have created an Azure search index and are having the published endpoint URL.

You can query the above JSON as request body along with your authentication details in the header of the request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gd, but I'd prefer to use the sitecore API, or I would need to create a wrapper per search provider